# How to avoid (handle) deadlock on insert operation?

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

In my small web service, I get a deadlock when trying to insert a new row in logs table - Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.

When I execute method Test many times, I get error. How can I avoid deadlock?

```
func main() {

    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", dbUser+":"+dbPassword+"@tcp("+dbAddr+")/"+dbDatabase)
    if err != nil {

        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {

        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    router := mux.NewRouter()


    router.HandleFunc("/test/", Test).Methods("POST")


    log.Error(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func Test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")


    w.Write(body)
    _ = insertLog("Test")
}

func insertLog(msg string) error {

    var sqlString string

    sqlString = "insert into logs (date_time, msg) values(now(),?)"

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(sqlString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return err
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    _, err = stmt.Exec(msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Msg: %s, Func: %s", err, function)
        return err
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    return err
}
```

Schema (from Comment):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (
    date_time datetime NOT NULL, 
    msg varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: For starters, you're closing the statement twice in defer.

Comment: How it related with deadlock?

Comment: I haven't checked what it does internally, just pointing it out. You may want to post your schema and more details about how you ran the test.

Comment: But this code is working. Database is 10.0.21-MariaDB-wsrep - MariaDB Server. go version go1.8 linux/amd64 mysql driver is github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql Table logs 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs ( date_time datetime NOT NULL, msg varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;code

Comment: should be great to see the imports you are using! maybe the issue is related to the db package

Comment: There's not enough context here to determine the problem. But it seems apparent that _something_ is locking the `logs` table, and not releasing the lock.

Comment: This is unrelated to Go and a common problem with InnoDB. The usual recommendation is: retry the transaction until it works. See [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_lock_deadlock).

Comment: @EddyHernandez
import (
 "bytes"
 "crypto/md5"
 "database/sql"
 "encoding/hex"
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
 "io/ioutil"
 "net/http"
 "strings"
 "time"

 l4g "github.com/alecthomas/log4go"

 "html/template"
 "strconv"

 _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
 "github.com/gorilla/mux"
 "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
 "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

Comment: @Flimzy 
I think another instance of insertLog function, cos I execute it from another methods too

Comment: you can't deadlock with only one resource... are you sure this insert is the only thing running? can you print something on error and confirm you actually get a deadlock in that code?

Answer (score -2):

You have no `PRIMARY KEY`; that is naughty.

Add

```
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

to the table definition.  (See `ALTER TABLE`.)

Comment: @giorgiga - Are you sure?